# Group by timestamp MYSQL outputting blank rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL Query of which is returning blank rows for each row returned.

The data is not echoing, but the rows are. I have no idea why this is occurring.

Why is this not working correctly?

**The MySQL/PHP**

```
$sql6x = " SELECT date(datetime), sum(row_total)
                 FROM sales_tickets
                 GROUP BY date(datetime);
                                "; 
                $result6x = mysql_query($sql6x);

                while ($row6x = mysql_fetch_array($result6x)) { 
                     echo $datetime = $row6x['datetime'].$br;   
                     echo $row_total = $row6x['row_total'].$br; 
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set aliases:

```
SELECT date(datetime) AS datetime, sum(row_total) AS row_total
...
```

or use `$row6x[0]` and `$row6x[1]`.